Intel IPP Illegal value for border type
The following code snippet reads a JPEG file into memory, does Cubic resize halfing by 2 with Intel IPP and then writes the resized memory blob into a different JPEG file.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <ipp.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <filename> <width> <height>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ippInit();

    const char *src_name = argv[1];
    FILE *src_file = fopen(src_name, "rb");
    if (src_file == NULL) {
        perror("fopen()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (fseek(src_file, 0, SEEK_END) == -1) {
        perror("fseek()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    long src_len = ftell(src_file);
    if (src_len == -1) {
        perror("ftell()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    rewind(src_file);

    Ipp8u *srcIpp = (Ipp8u *) ippsMalloc_8u(src_len);
    if (srcIpp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "There is not enough memory for allocating srcIpp\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (fread(srcIpp, src_len, 1, src_file) == -1) {
        perror("fread()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (fclose(src_file) == EOF) {
        perror("fclose()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    const size_t src_width = (size_t) atol(argv[2]);
    const size_t src_height = (size_t) atol(argv[3]);

    const size_t dst_width = (size_t) src_width / 2;
    const size_t dst_height = (size_t) src_height / 2;

    const short num_channels = 3;

    Ipp8u *dstIpp = (Ipp8u *) ippsMalloc_8u(dst_width * dst_height * num_channels);
    if (dstIpp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "There is not enough memory for allocating dstIpp\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    IppiResizeSpec_32f *ippSpec = 0;
    int specSize = 0, initSize = 0, bufSize = 0;
    Ipp8u *ippBuffer = 0;
    Ipp8u *initBuf = 0;
    Ipp32u numChannels = 3;
    IppiPoint dstOffset = { 0, 0 };
    IppiBorderType border = ippBorderDefault;
    int srcStep = src_width * 3;
    int dstStep = dst_width * 3;
    IppiSize srcSize = { src_width, src_height };
    IppiSize dstSize = { dst_width, dst_height };
    IppStatus ippStatus;

    ippStatus = ippiResizeGetSize_8u(srcSize, dstSize, ippCubic, 0, &specSize, &initSize);
    if (ippStatus != ippStsNoErr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ippiResizeGetSize_8u(): %s\n", ippGetStatusString(ippStatus));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    initBuf = (Ipp8u *) ippsMalloc_8u(initSize);
    if (initBuf == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "There is not enough memory for allocating initBuf\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ippSpec = (IppiResizeSpec_32f *) ippsMalloc_8u(specSize);
    if (ippSpec == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "There is not enough memory for allocating ippSpec\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ippStatus = ippiResizeCubicInit_8u(srcSize, dstSize, 1, 1, ippSpec, initBuf);
    if (ippStatus != ippStsNoErr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ippiResizeCubicInit_8u(): %s\n", ippGetStatusString(ippStatus));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ippsFree(initBuf);

    ippStatus = ippiResizeGetBufferSize_8u(ippSpec, dstSize, numChannels, &bufSize);
    if (ippStatus != ippStsNoErr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ippiResizeGetBufferSize_8u(): %s\n", ippGetStatusString(ippStatus));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ippBuffer = (Ipp8u *) ippsMalloc_8u(bufSize);
    if (ippBuffer == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "There is not enough memory for allocating ippBuffer\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ippStatus = ippiResizeCubic_8u_C3R(srcIpp, srcStep, dstIpp, dstStep, dstOffset, dstSize, border, 0, ippSpec, ippBuffer);
    if (ippStatus != ippStsNoErr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ippiResizeCubic_8u_C3R(): %s\n", ippGetStatusString(ippStatus));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    FILE *dst_file = fopen("IPP.JPG", "wb");
    if (dst_file == NULL) {
        perror("fopen()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (fwrite(dstIpp, sizeof(*dstIpp), 1, dst_file) == -1) {
        perror("fwrite()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (fclose(dst_file) == EOF) {
        perror("fclose()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ippsFree(ippSpec);
    ippsFree(ippBuffer);
    ippsFree(srcIpp);
    ippsFree(dstIpp);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


But the following error arises:
ippiResizeCubic_8u_C3R(): ippStsBorderErr: Illegal value for border type
and if I change the border type to ippBorderConst I get the following:
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==18018==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x799774aa64c0 (pc 0x79976e59e807 bp 0x000000000000 sp 0x7ffe382618b0 T0)
==18018==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
    #0 0x79976e59e807 in l9_ownCalcBorderR3Cubic8u (/opt/intel/oneapi/ipp/2021.11/lib/libippil9.so.10.10+0x139e807)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV (/opt/intel/oneapi/ipp/2021.11/lib/libippil9.so.10.10+0x139e807) in l9_ownCalcBorderR3Cubic8u
==18018==ABORTING

Code was compiled with:
gcc -std=c11 -fsanitize=address -g -o test test.c -I/opt/intel/oneapi/ipp/2021.11/include/ -L/opt/intel/oneapi/ipp/2021.11/lib/ -lippcore -lipps -lippi

and run with:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/oneapi/ipp/2021.11/lib/ ./test <filename> <width> <height>

Some suggestions ?
Gianluca
